# Executing postgres initialization scripts when running cypress on CI

Tags: postgresql, gitlab-ci, cypress

I'm trying to run Cypress on gitlab CI.

Everything works as expected, but one little thing.. my DB initialization script (which runs after every test) won't work. This problem fails my tests, as well as the CI job.

After some thinking, I've realized that the `setup.sh` script contains `psql` command which connects to db and needs postgres
(on local machine the tests run successfully since I do have postgres installed locally).

I'm using `cypress_included:3.8.0` image which doesn't contain postgres. Any ideas how to solve the issue? is there any workaround? should I manually try to install it myself? (if so, it would be nice to see an example)

Thanks!

Comment: In [Cypress's official GitHub page](https://github.com/cypress-io), there is an [example `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) for [running Cypress in continuous integration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since `cypress/included:3.8.0` image is using `Debian` OS, thus you can use `apt-get` command inside your job scripts to install some dependencies or packages.
If you want to install both <kbd>PostgreSQL core database server</kbd> and <kbd>PostgreSQL client (psql)</kbd>, you can add the following commands to your `CI / CD` job `scripts` like below:

```
image: cypress/included:3.8.0

⋮

foo job:
    scripts:
        ...
        - apt-get update -qy && apt-get upgrade -qy
        - apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib
        ...
⋮
```

If you just want to install <kbd>PostgreSQL client (psql)</kbd>, remove packages `postgresql` and `postgresql-client` from the command:

```
image: cypress/included:3.8.0

⋮

foo job:
    scripts:
        ...
        - apt-get update -qy && apt-get upgrade -qy
        - apt-get install -y postgresql-client
        ...
⋮
```